# Jquery/Javascript: do something based on user typing time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assuming i've this simple html:

```
<input type="text" id="inputId" /><img id="imgId" src="images/myImage.gif" style="display:none" />
```

now i want to do this:

1) When someone write in the input i want to show the image
1) When the user stop to write in the input or the input is empty for 1-2 seconds i want to hide the image

i Know how to show or hide the image:

```
$('#imgId').css('display', '')
```

or

```
$('#imgId').css('display', 'none')
```

but i don't know how to add the timing.

Thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2UrAA/2/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somethingk like that

```
var initial;

function invocation() {
    initial = window.setTimeout( 
    function() {
        $("#imgId").hide();
    }, 2000);
}



$('#inputId').keypress(function() {

    $("#imgId").hide();
    clearTimeout( initial );
    invocation();
});
```

see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/znqPR/1/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use window.setTimeout(myfunction, delay) and restart the timeout every change of the input. So after 2 seconds of no input myfunction will execute. Comment if you would like help writing it.

Also jquery has hide() and show() functions instead of manually changing the css.

Answer (score 0):

Use keydown(),keyup() events

```
$( "#inputAreaID" ).keydown(function(){
    $('#imgId').css('display', 'block')
});

$( "#inputAreaID" ).keyup(function(){
    $('#imgId').css('display', 'none')
});
```